# Caffe/pyCaffe: set all GPUs

Tags: parallel-processing, neural-network, gpu, deep-learning, caffe

is possible to set all GPUs for Caffe (especially pyCaffe)?

Something like:

```
caffe train -solver examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt -gpu all
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33446612/1714410

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK Caffe is not supporting multi gpu training at the moment. It is planned for future release. See a discussion [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/876).
It seems like [NVIDIA's branch of caffe](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe) has this functionality. See the issue [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/92).

Comment: Seems this is outdated info?

Comment: @Shai: Any update on this? is it still not possible to utilize multiple GPUs in Pycaffe?

Comment: @Shai: Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 7):

Both forks have supported multi-GPU for a while now.

- BVLC/caffe got support for multi-GPU on 08/13/2015 (see [commit](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/commit/bb0a90e8aabb0e1ffd5732439591814d10d7fd45), [issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2903)).
- NVIDIA/caffe got support for multi-GPU on 06/19/2015 (see [release note](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe/releases/tag/v0.12.0)).

You may be interested to know that there is a pretty serious outstanding issue with multi-GPU and PythonLayers (see [issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2936), [temporary fix](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3032)).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Caffe now starts supporting training on multi-GPUs for C++ interface.
See the docs on [CommandLine interface](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html).

```
# train on GPUs 0 & 1 (doubling the batch size)
caffe train -solver examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt -gpu 0,1
# train on all GPUs (multiplying batch size by number of devices)
caffe train -solver examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt -gpu all
```

Comment: How much speedup did you gain?

Comment: Hi @nn0p, the speedup is nearly linear.

Comment: with or without NCCL? And I think the net's size also affect the speedup ratio.

Comment: Hi @nn0p, NCCL is only a library to read data, not for computation.